# Woocommerce - Show total items on order details

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I'm trying to show the total (quantity) of items purchased on order details after the checkout.

I put the code on checkout page, and work's very well:

`<tr class="cart-subtotal">
    <th><?php _e( 'Product Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
    <td><?php global $woocommerce; ?><?php echo sprintf(_n('%d', '%d', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count);?></td>
</tr>.`

Any idea how i put this on order detail? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use 2 filters in the template `woocommerce/templates/order/order-details.php`, I think it's better to use filter rather than copy and edit the template file (when it's possible).

You can use `woocommerce_order_items_table` or `woocommerce_order_details_after_order_table`, the first stands in the main table, the second one after.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_order_items_table', 'add_items_count_on_order_page');

function add_items_count_on_order_page($order){
   ?>
    <tr class="cart-subtotal">
       <th><?php _e( 'Product Quantity', 'woocommerce' ); ?></th>
       <td><?php echo $order->get_item_count();?></td>
    </tr>
   <?php
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Worked!! Thank's for the help and explication!

Comment: Great, don't know how you did it before, but it can save a lot of time!